# Visual Studio 2008, easy way to manage settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, settings

Is there a plugin or some hidden feature in Visual Studio 2008 that allows for easy swapping between user settings files?  Using the import/export wizard all the time gets a little bit tedious.  It would be nice if there was a menu item called "Profiles" that you could set up to contain different profiles with different settings and change them on the fly.

Comment: I'd love this as well. It would be even better if a solution could be associated with a profile...

Comment: Sounds like we should get some people together and cook something up.  Unfortunately I am just a novice ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is may be something else available but I have a neat way to achieve what you want.

In VS, Tools > External Tools (w.r.t. VS2005). Here you can write your commands and tools to be executed, using menu. Now, what you can do here is swap the setting files and restart VS instance. You can have as many as menus for profile 1...n

Update: Example1 
Title:     Set Profile 1 
Command:   %windir%\system32\replace.exe 
Arguments: "C:\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings" "D:\Profile1\CurrentSettings.vssettings"

This should replace the settings with that of Profile 1. Also, add command to relaunch Devenv.

Comment: Could elaborate on this a little bit?  Is it possible to post a screenshot or something.  I was poking around with the external tools dialog like you said but I dont see how I can do anything in there to accomplish what I want.